# Empty bytes32[] in truffle console

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am trying to get from truffle develop console an array of identifiers using a custom get function but the return array is `[]`. 
Here is my contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract MyInfo {

  struct Info {
    bytes32 id;
    bytes32 name;
  }
  bytes32[] infoIDs;
  mapping(bytes32 => Info) infos;
  function addInfo(bytes32 _name) public
     returns(bool success) {

     bytes32 ID = keccak256(_name);
     infoIDs.push(ID);
     infos[ID].id = ID;
     infos[ID].name =_name;
     return true;
  }
  function getInfoIDs() public view returns(bytes32[] ids) {
    return infoIDs;
  }
}
```

And from the truffle console I run:

> MyInfo.deployed().then(inst => { return inst.addInfo("testname", {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}) })

which returns true.

To get the ids I run:

> MyInfo.deployed().then(inst => { return inst.getInfoIDs.call() })

but I get `[]`.

Any ideas what it might be the problem?

I'm using

> Truffle v4.1.0 (core: 4.1.0)

and

> Solidity v0.4.19 (solc-js)

EDIT: If I put the code in Remix I get the ids correct.

EDIT2: I noticed that the values assigned to other variables inside the addInfo function don't exist afterwards...

Answer (score 1):

I can verify that your code work with:
Truffle v4.0.6 (core: 4.0.6)
Solidity v0.4.19 (solc-js)

Have you deployed your code? I get the "[]" if I do not first deploy the MyInfo.sol contract. See if this works:

Try adding a file "2_deploy.js" to your migration folder with the following code:

var MyInfo = artifacts.require("./MyInfo.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
    deployer.deploy(MyInfo)
};

Then from the Truffle development console enter "truffle migrate". This will deploy the MyInfo contract. After this your two commands should work.

For more info checkout http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/migrations

Comment: Problem solved by restarting truffle dev.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the contract is deployed before you try to call `addInfo`.

Try putting your call to `getInfoIDs` in another `then` block after
`return inst.addInfo("testname", {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]})`.

It may be that you are doing the call to the accessor before the promise which writes the data has resolved (but after the promise has been returned).